# Update grayed out (Xorg X server -- QXL display driver)

Tags: xorg, qml

I've been ignoring this issue for a while since it didn't effect anything on my system. But its annoying to watch this one little update graded out while the rest of the updates get installed.

[image]

Any solutions ?

Comment: If you go to the Terminal and do the upgrade with `dist-upgrade` it will prompt you to remove the xorg-all package (you can imagine this is not a good idea, though you can re-install it) . You *can* leave it like that unless you need whatever the update to the QXL display driver brings.

Comment: tried it but din't work.

Comment: What didn't worked?.

Answer (score 0):

Run this on terminal

```
sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-video-qxl
```