# Upgrade to ubuntu 12.10 fails with calculation error

Tags: 12.10, upgrade, updates

I wanted to upgrade to 13.04 and as a necessity I need to update to 12.10. I have successfully updated in the past from Ubuntu 10 to Ubuntu 11 ans 12.04. Somehow, when I try from terminal or from update manager the update fails with shown in the following error.

[image: Screenshot of the Error]

I have also submitted the bug report via launchpad. I don't wish to update using dvd to save applications. Any alternative?

Have submitted as bug at [Bug Launcpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/1193427)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems other users [didn't face this issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/260832/update-grayed-out-xorg-x-server-qxl-display-driver).

Remove any packages, that are greyed out. Like in my case: `xserver-xorg-video-qxl` and `xserver-xorg-video-openchrome`. And then the usual step:

```
sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-video-qxl
sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-video-openchrome
sudo apt-get update
```

It's working.

Answer (score 1):

In a [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal) run next commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

**Edit:** Also, try to [choose another download server](https://askubuntu.com/a/308348/147044).

Comment: I tried this. but it fails.

Comment: Got following output

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  xserver-xorg-video-openchrome xserver-xorg-video-qxl
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.

Comment: What is the result of `sudo apt-get update`? Put the result in http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/

Comment: here it is 

http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/5787446/

Comment: @MalTec I would suggest reverting to other country's server instead of the main archive.ubuntu.com

Comment: nope. still not working. fetches software channels well. fails at "calculating changes" . Running from terminal doesn't affect at all.

Comment: removing packages that were not updating helped. Removed removed xserver-xorg-video-openchrome xserver-xorg-video-qxl. It worked. Thanks :)